# Remove little gray box from content page

Tags: tags

[image]

Hello!
I would like to remove the 'em' element from the code using the 'additional CSS' function (or other way) since it appears on the main page has a little gray box. I have attached an image to clarify what I mean.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you track down which structure on the page it belongs to, e.g. is it part of the div that contains the 'travel' image (e.g. it's a caption or similar in the media library for that image), or the div that contains all of those three images, or somewhere else? Ideally you'll need to find a unique or uncommon class name of an element that contains the em, then find that in your site's files, to work out what's generating it. This may be your theme, or a WooCommerce template, or something else.

Comment: You could hide it with CSS yes, using some or all of the line of selectors under the tag hierarchy view in your browser tools (which is cut off in your screenshot), but if it were me I'd try and track down exactly what was generating it.

Comment: @Rup, Yes, the structure to which it belongs is this one:
<div class='elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix'>
I got what you meant. What should I do now to fix the problem?